# SQLite count, group and order by count (with separator |)

Tags: sqlite

i want count an SQLITE-Database there movie-Genren.

In the database are as example saves the Genres, 3 examples:

```
Genres
---------
Action 
Western|Crime
Drama|Western|Comedy|Horror
```

Anybody an solution for me?

Comment: Is this for homework?  You should show what you have tried and only ask a question if you cannot get it working.  Stack Overflow is not a "free solution" service.

Comment: Edit the question and provide exactly what result / output that you expect.  It is not clear how you expect the items to be ordered and grouped and counted.  Sqlite normally expects data to be in properly normalized columns.  Having multi-valued text with delimiters is a challenge in itself and will either require processing outside of SQL or possibly using recursive CTE and window functions, both advanced topics.

Answer (score 0):

The question is still too vague, but in honor of the "be nice" and "answer anything" movement on Stack Overflow, here's a start of solution:

```
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie;

CREATE TEMP TABLE movie
(id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
genres TEXT);

INSERT INTO movie (genres)
VALUES
   ('Action'),
   ('Western|Crime'),
   ('Drama|Western|Comedy|Horror');

*/

WITH RECURSIVE split AS (
     SELECT id, 
            0 AS num,
            instr(genres,'|') AS delimit,
            null AS genre, 
            genres AS remain
     FROM movie
     WHERE genres is not null
     UNION
     SELECT 
            id,
            num + 1 AS num,
            CASE WHEN delimit <= 0 THEN -1
                 ELSE instr(substr(remain, delimit + 1),'|') END AS delimit, 
            CASE WHEN delimit <= 0 THEN remain 
                 ELSE substr(remain, 1, delimit -1) END AS genre,
            CASE WHEN delimit <= 0 THEN null 
                 ELSE substr(remain, delimit + 1) END AS remain
     FROM split
     WHERE delimit >= 0
)
SELECT id, num, genre
FROM split
WHERE genre is not null
ORDER BY id, num;
```